# linq to sql SubmitChanges not firing triggers with multiple InsertOnSubmit or DeleteOnSubmit

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am using linq to sql and have a trigger defined to update counts in another table if rows are removed or added from the table with the trigger on it. If I call one InsertOnSubmit or one DeleteOnSubmit and then call SubmitChanges, the trigger fires. If I call more than one of either InsertOnSubmit or DeleteOnSubmit and then call SubmitChanges, the trigger does not fire.

Has anyone experienced this and does anyone know of a way to fix it? The only workaround right now is to call SubmitChanges after every InsertOnSubmit or DeleteOnSubmit...

The database backend is sql server 2008 standard r2, I am running C# 4.0 using the built in linq to sql designer functionality.

Comment: Are you very sure that your trigger isn't dropping the data? perhaps checking nest-level, or perhaps not quite handling single/multi row changes...? It **should** work just fine...

Comment: Hey Marc, I did double check the trigger and it seemed to be working, I also found the problem and left an answer. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently LINQ to SQL is smart enough to do an update instead of a delete and then an insert if you are deleting a row and then re-adding a row with the same primary key. My trigger was only for inserts and deletes and therefore never saw the update come through. I have modified the trigger accordingly and everything works now!

Comment: InsertOnSubmit "undoes" DeleteOnSubmit (and vice versa) if called before SubmitChanges(), as you found.  Just a different way to think about it.

Comment: +1 on this because it's actually the answer, whereas my answer just helped you find it :)

Comment: Thanks, I am glad you made that suggestion, I would have spent hours pulling my hair out otherwise

Answer (score 2):

I am hoping that the reason you ask the question is because you know that technically this behaviour is impossible, since L2S generates insert statements just like you would manually or in a stored procedure :)

Are you sure it's not firing the trigger, or is it *only firing the trigger once* for all the insertions? I've not been able to model the scenario (forgot to install ssms on my home pc - like to use it primarily for gaming ;) ) but this question: [SQL Server Trigger that works - fires just once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072314/sql-server-trigger-that-works-fires-just-once) (read pablo santa cruz's answer) shows that the trigger will only fire once for each insert statement.  So if there is one insert statement which bulk-inserts from a whole rowset then the trigger fires only once, and the `inserted` identifier in the trigger contains all of those rows.

If L2S is doing something clever and spooling the insertions from a temporary table, or table variable, then you might only see one trigger execution.

Attach `Console.Out` to your DataContext's `Log` property and examine the SQL that is being generated on submit - then you can copy that and execute it manually in SSMS to examine the behaviour.

As an aside I spend most of my life avoiding triggers - so I'm not the greatest authority on their behaviour - I tend to think of them doing nothing but making my life a bloody misery (whilst knowing that they serve a very useful purpose)!

So, sorry, no hard-and-fast answer - but hopefully a few pointers there.

Comment: Found it, I will leave an answer so others can be aware of what linq does under the hood :)

Comment: @JJC - cool - glad to be of help.  I suppose if you think about it you *are* just doing an update - L2S is taking the shortest route in Database terms to mirror the data changes you want.